# Why am I not getting the dates I have chosen?

Tags: php

I have a form which allows the user to input two dates but the dates are incorrect on my output as it comes up with 1970-01-01.
Any help?

Here is my HTML for date1:

```
 <td><label for="date_1">Date as dd/mm/yyyy (date_1)</label></td>
        <td>
          <input name="date_1" type="text" class="larger" id="date_1" value="" size="12" />
```

Here is my php:

```
$first = $_REQUEST["date_1"];
$second = $_REQUEST["date_2"];

$f_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($first));
$s_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($second));

if(isset($_GET["submit"])){

echo $f_date;
echo '<br />';
echo $s_date;
```

Comment: `strtotime` does not understand the `dd/mm/yyyy` format (it will think you're parsing `mm/dd/yyyy`). Use `yyyy-mm-dd` or [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: `$foo = strtotime($first); var_dump($foo)`. you'll find it's a boolean FALSE, which gets cast to integer 0 when you use it as the timestamp arg in `date`, which converts to the epoch date - Jan 1/1970

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), when the function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), the constructor of class [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and its procedural equivalent (the function [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)) find a slash (`/`) in the date provided to them to parse, they interpret it as a separator for either American date style (`month`/`day`/`year`) or `year`/`month`/`day` format. Which one they attempt to parse depends on the number of digits found in the first component: `4` digits triggers the parsing for `y/m/d` format, `1` or `2` digits start parsing for the `m/d/y` format. There is no `d/m/y` using `/` as a separator.

You can either use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (and you can provide the desired format to the parser) or enforce an universal format (`yyyy-mm-dd`, for example) that is not ambiguous and can be parsed by `strtotime()` and the rest of the functions without needing further instructions.